# Android: can't debug file writting code because my SD card gets mounted

Tags: android, debugging, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am programming a temporary file-downloader inside my app. That file-downloader is crashing. The problem is: I can't debug it, because when the phone is connected to the computer, the SD card gets locked and it can't write files. That is, it crashes because of that, and that's the error I see - hiding the actual error that is making it crash when it is not mounted.

Comment: remove the tick mark from option, "connect USB mass storage", then it will be only in debug mode, and you can test your application properly :)

Comment: Also you can define your proper logging in the code and use application like logcat in your device to collect logs without connecting to your computer.

Comment: @Lucifer where? On Eclipse? On the phone?

Comment: of course on, phone, when you connect the phone with USB cable, it shows that option in the phone,

Comment: @Lucifer where? On the status bar? There is 'Connected as a media device / Touch for other USB options". Inside it there's: "Media device (MTP) / Allows you to transfer media files in Windows, or using Android file transfer on a Mac...". There's nothing about "connect USB mass storage". On "Settings" there's nothing too. Using Galaxy s2.

Comment: @Lucifer there's a button 'Connect storage to PC' below a title "USB mass storage", on config > more ... > USB Utilities. It is not 'tickable'. If I press it it says 'USB is connected. Remove the cable'.

Comment: it must be showing in the notifications, please check it

Comment: @Lucifer that's what I meant with status bar, sorry. I would like to take a screenshot but I'm not sure how I do that. Hold on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if SD card is mounted prior using it:

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
                        android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

      // ok, you can use SD card...
}
```

as, as comments above state, on some devices SD card access from host computer can block device's access to it. Also just in case, ensure your manifest request SD card permissions too.